# How can I rotate Nodes in a splay tree?

Tags: java, tree, splay-tree

The code I have is

```
private Node rotateLeftChild(Node n)
{
    Node o = n.left;
    n.left = o.right;
    o.right = n;
    return o;
}
```

When I call it to rotate a tree like this at the root:

```
             7
            / \
           4   8
          / \   
         1   5
```

it deletes the 4 and 1 and makes 5 the left root of 7.  I tried just making the method a  void method but that doesn't seem to work either.  Am I going at this the completely wrong way?

Comment: By "rotate", do you mean swapping `4` and `8` relative to `7` (ie swapping `left` and `right`)?

Comment: Have you tried to debug? I would put a break-point at *return o* to check. I don't think there's an issue with your left rotation code though, the problem might be somewhere higher up (*maybe where you're trying to use your rotation code*)

Comment: This is a supporting method, but right now it isn't working when I just use it by itself.

Comment: In this case I'm trying to make 4 the root and 7 it's right Node.

Comment: Hey, everything is alright, your code is totally wrong. Explanation: parent of 7 still contains link to a 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first, sorry for my English.

Answer to a question - why node 4 dissapears is simple. 7 have parent node (or 7 is root). When you call rotateLeftChild, parent of 7 still "thinking" that his child is 7, not 4:

[image: Real picture]

So, there are tree solutions:

1. Make link to a parent node and update it. In the end of leftRotation, make assignment, n.Parent.Left = o or n.Parent.Right = o (if (n.Parent.Left == n) or (n.Parent.Right == n) respectively). Of course, you must update links to tree's root, when you rotate child of root.
2. When you are adding | inserting | finding node, save all previous (parent) nodes in stack, and then after rotation you must update links to their children. Or use recursion like this:

   ```
   private Splay(Node parent, Node cur, Node n, bool canMoveUpTwice = false) {
       if (cur.Value > n.Value)
           Splay(cur, cur.Left, n, !canMoveUpTwice);
       else
           Splay(cur, cur.Right, n, !canMoveUpTwice);

       if (canMoveUpTwice)
           MoveUpTwice();
       else
           MoveUpOnce();

       if (parent.Left == cur)
           parent.Left = n;
       else
           parent.Right = n;

       if (Parent == null)
           tree.Root = n;
   }
   ```

   How to use. After adding node, you must run Splay(root, newNode). Be sure, you'll get stack overflow.
3. You must swap values of nodes and then think that nodes have been swapped. In standart implementation of rotation we have such picture: 
   [image: Simple rotations]
   In rotation with swaps we get this (=x means "node have value X"):
   [image: Rotations by swap]
   So, we have this code

   ```
   private rotateLeftChild(Node q) {
       Node p = q.Left;

       Swap(q.Value, p.Value); 

       A = p.Left;
       B = p.Right;
       C = q.Right;

       q.Left  = A;
       q.Right = p;

       p.Left  = B;
       p.Right = C;
   }
   ```

Be careful: the code has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check what the parent node thought of.